# Reorganize data.frame into tabulation of values

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,1,2,3,3), y = c(letters[1:5],'a'), val = c(1:5, 9))
print(df)
  x y val
  1 a   1
  2 b   2
  1 c   3
  2 d   4
  3 e   5
  3 a   9
```

I want to create a function `fun(df, rowname, colname, valname)`that takes a dataframe, rowname, colname, and value inputs and returns a data.frame or matrix with row names, column names and values as shown below

```
fun(df, "x","y","val") should return

    1 2 3
 a  1 NA 9
 b  NA 2 NA
 c  3 NA NA
 d  NA 4  NA  
 e  NA NA 5
```

Comment: Take a look at the reshape2 package, the function `cast` and `melt` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: library(dplyr);
spread(df, x, val)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reshape2 library allows this kind of manipulation:

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(data=df, y~x, value.var = "val")

  y  1  2  3
1 a  1 NA  9
2 b NA  2 NA
3 c  3 NA NA
4 d NA  4 NA
5 e NA NA  5
```

Comment: With base R's `reshape`: `reshape(df, direction="wide", idvar="y", timevar="x")`.